Why is it OK to cancel out terms when solving partial fractions?
When solving a partial fraction, one of the steps is to arrive at an algebraic identity. For example, consider partial fraction below:
$$\frac{(2x + 1)}{(  − 1 )(  + 2 )} = \frac{A}{(x-1)} + \frac{B}{(x+2)}$$
After multiplying both sides by $(  − 1 ) (  + 2 )$ we get:
$$2x+1=A(x+2)+B(x−1)$$
Later on to determine, $A$, for example, we can set $x = 1$. My question is, why is this allowed? When we cancel out the denominators, do we not implicitly assume that $x \neq 1, -2$? Then why immediately in the next step do we break this assumption?

If you prefer, you can simply expand the right hand to get $(A+B)x+(2A-B)$  and then match coefficients to get $A+B=2, 2A-B=1$.

Should have said, I agree that "setting $x=1$" seems risky since $1$ is outside the domain of the expression we are working with.  One could argue in terms of limits and such, but I think that matching coefficients resolves the issue more simply.

@lulu It's true that you avoid that issue, but when working with $5$ or $6$ fractions, matching the coefficients and solving the system of equations is much more work than simply giving values to $x$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333589/53537

You're right that the original equation only makes sense for $x\neq 1,-2$. However, once you've arrived at
$$2x+1=A(x+2)+B(x-1)$$
this is a polynomial equation, i.e. it states that two polynomials are equal. It is a general fact that if two polynomials are equal at an infinite number of points, then they are equal everywhere. In particular, if your polynomials are equal everywhere except at $x= 1,-2$, then they are also equal at these points as well, and you actually can set $x=1$ to figure out the coefficients.
However, as others pointed out, you don't need to set $x$ to any particular value: polynomials being equal means that their coefficients are equal, which reduces the equation to a system
$$2=A+B \\ 1=2A-B$$


It is a general fact that if two polynomials are equal at an infinite number of points, then they are equal everywhere.

Is this a theorem I can read about? I did not know this to be true.

It's pretty well-known, and it's discussed for example in this question.

@abhink It boils down to polynomials only having a finite numbers of roots. So if two polynomials are equal on some set $p=q$, it means that $p-q=0$ on this set, and $p-q$ is also a polynomial, so either the set is finite, or $p-q$ is the zero polynomial, meaning that $p=q$ holds everywhere.

expect -> except? (too few characters to suggest an edit, please flag this comment after it has been revised)

@AndrewT. Fixed, thank you!

We don't set $x=1$ to determine $A$. The coefficients are found by comparing the coefficients of the different $x$ terms on either side of the equation.
For example, your equation becomes $$2x+1=(A+B)x+2A-B$$ For the equation to be valid for any possible value of $x$, the only way that is possible is if the coefficients were equal. That is; $$A+B=2$$$$2A-B=1$$ which is a system of two unknowns and two equations which we can solve: take the sum of the two expressions to get $$3A=3 \rightarrow A=1 \rightarrow 1+B=2 \rightarrow B=1$$
At no point do we set $x=1$. Indeed, as you say, the expression is undefined for $x=1$ as we can't divide by $0$.

It's actually quite common to shortcut to the solution by setting suitable values of $x$, especially when there are only a couple of terms.

huh, I was not aware of that! Thanks (and sorry for the incorrect/incomplete answer)
